# Stacking np.tril and np.triu together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two correlation matrices, one which has the lower triangle as `NaN` values, and the other one that has its upper triangle as 'NaN' values.

I would like to stack them together, so I would end up with a NxN matrix with correlation coefficients.

I tried using `pd.concat()`, but I can't get it to work. I am looking for a better way to do this, as I am sure there is one

```py
a = [1, NaN, NaN,
     0.4, 1, NaN,
     0.7, 0.3, 1]

b = [1, 0.2, 0.9,
     NaN, 1, 0.6,
     NaN, NaN, 1]
```

I would like to have something that looks like this:

```py
c = [1, 0.2, 0.9,
     0.4, 1, 0.6,
     0.7, 0.3, 1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have `numpy` arrays you can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): `c=np.where(np.isnan(a), b, a)`

Comment: Use of `np.tril` in the subject line is misleading.  That function sets a block of elements to 0, not `nan`.  With 0's it's possible to add the two arrays together (though the shared diagonal complicates things).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for replace missing values by another `DataFrame`:

```
df = df1.fillna(df2)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

All together:

```
a = [1, np.nan, np.nan,
     0.4, 1, np.nan,
     0.7, 0.3, 1]

b = [1, 0.2, 0.9,
     np.nan, 1, 0.6,
     np.nan, np.nan, 1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(a).reshape(3,3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(b).reshape(3,3))

df = df1.fillna(df2)
print (df)
     0    1    2
0  1.0  0.2  0.9
1  0.4  1.0  0.6
2  0.7  0.3  1.0
```